# Change card height and make it responsive Boostrap 5

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel and a card next to each other both responsive to any break points but the problem is I want to increase the height of my card to be bigger than the carousel and push down the carousel to be In the middle of the big card

Change card height and make it responsive to all breakpoints using Boostrap

Comment: Please show some code for this. Everyone just has to take a guess at what to change. No one can help you with code if you don't show any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.